# Allowing users to create specific routes in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, subdomain

In my Rails app users have possibility to enter their own domain for their page if they want. The value of the domain name saving in the database.

For now routes are look something like this: `/user/sites/3`. 
So, for example, user entered domain name as: "mystuff". And previous route should change to this: `/mystuff`

How can  implement this?
Thank you.

Comment: Here's an article about custom dynamic routing in Rails 4 : http://codeconnoisseur.org/ramblings/creating-dynamic-routes-at-runtime-in-rails-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's an example from [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) on how your route should look like:

```
get ':username', to: 'users#show', as: :user
```

this produces route such as `/bob` refering to users controller show action

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean domain? you mean sub-domain or sub-url? 
If you want to create sub-url for MyStuff (eg. http://www.domain.com/mystuff)
  1) you need to create slug field to parameterized the text which you want to be sub-url.(or) can also use parameterized method. (eg. My Stuff => my-stuff)
  2) create a route 
       get ":site_slug", to: 'home#site'